# Calculating distance between camera and object real time

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo

I am so new to this area. I want to improve myself and I need your advices. I want to detect objects and find the distances between the objects and my camera by using a phone camera. What should I learn in order to achive this? Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: not really an appropriate question for StackOverflow but I will put forward one piece of advice, calibration is key! Now off to Google with you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the following: "a single picture, taken with any camera, at any distance, and calculate the distance given an image", then I fear that might be impossible, because there is no depth with a single view. It would be pretty impossible for a nn to just guess how far an object is away by how big an image is. Retrieved from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_perception):

> Depth perception arises from a variety of depth cues. These are
> typically classified into binocular cues that are based on the receipt
> of sensory information in three dimensions from both eyes and
> monocular cues that can be represented in just two dimensions and
> observed with just one eye

Now this is out of the way, you did say YOUR camera, using a specific camera changes things, if you know the focal length and angle of view, that would help a lot. Here are some links to illustrate that:

[focal length](https://photographylife.com/what-is-focal-length-in-photography)

[angle of view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view#Calculating_a_camera%27s_angle_of_view)

Maybe you can calculate your way out of this, but you will need some constraints or callibration, one way or another. Hope I helped a bit